# How do I prevent special characters with Codeigniter's form validation?

Tags: codeigniter

I have a username field that I don't want to accept characters like `{*)&(%^%()_}`. What do I need to add to my form validation rules?

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('user_name' 'User Name', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|xss_clean');
```

Comment: There is no question here... Please try to rephrase and ask a question.

Comment: ...and don't forget to explain what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: Restrict the use of special characters in username, im using codeigniter framework. $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_name', 'User Name', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|xss_clean'); i have given for few regulations for username now i want to set restriction in username field and want to add more code in this above code line. im stuck here

Comment: restriction should be like it doesn't accept *^&*%^&#*^*&) these characters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just read the [doc](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html). It's not that hard.

If you want to restrict the username characters to letters and numbers, use the `alpha_numeric` rule.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('user_name', 'User Name', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|xss_clean|alpha_numeric');
```

But in case you want to restrict to letters only, use the `alpha` rule. Or if you want to restrict the username to letters, numbers, underscores, and dashes, use the `alpha_dash` rule.

Comment: thanks alot @kemal it was really very helpful its working

Comment: @ArunKumar, please click the "V" next to this answer to accept it. This does two things: it show other users that the question has a satisfactory answer (no need for new answers). And it show appreciation in the form of [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) for Kemal's effort.

Comment: @Mischa sorry but i can't see any "V" out here

Comment: There is no `V`; it's called a "check-mark".

Answer (score 0):

you should use callback functions to check the if the username matches the pattern:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'username_check');
....
public function username_check($str)
{
    if ($str == 'test')
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('username_check', 'The %s field can not be the word "test"');
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```